# code for changing "Mouse Highlight" color

Tags: web, colors, highlight

I use artisteer for making joomla template, I use this code:

```
.newsdate {
background: #f0f0f0;
color: #737373;
padding: 10px;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
text-align:center;
}
.art-blockheader .t, .art-vmenublockheader .t {white-space: nowrap;}
#art-licence-links 
{ 
display:none; 
} 
::selection
{
color:#FF4300;
}
::-moz-selection
{
color:#FF4300;
}
```

and my highlight color changes like [this](http://is200.imagesocket.com/thumbs/2013/10/22/2657998-hi7x.png)

but I want it to change like [this](http://is200.imagesocket.com/images/2013/10/22/2657997-8ao6.png)

Comment: Use a `background-color`?

Comment: how make selection area's text turn white?

Comment: Well, just use `color: white` in your `::selection` pseudo-selector...

Comment: tanx, but how? I'm noob, tried some combinations and had no luck.

Comment: There you go. You simply add the `color` to your `::selection` body. [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/EnumAVAV/1/watch?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `::selection` and `::-moz-selection` blocks add `backgound-color` property and specify the color of the selected background.

Comment: I did this:
`.newsdate {
background: #f0f0f0;
color: #737373;
padding: 10px;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
text-align:center;
}
.art-blockheader .t, .art-vmenublockheader .t {white-space: nowrap;}
#art-licence-links 
{ 
display:none; 
} 
::selection
{
background-color:#FF4300;
}
::-moz-selection
{
background-color:#FF4300;
}
`
this happend: [link](http://is200.imagesocket.com/images/2013/11/22/2660964-mq5v.png)

so much better, but how can I make it that the text turns white not black in selection area?